# Failing to Redirect Output to File

Tags: command-line, time, redirect, stdout

I want to redirect output from "time" to a file.  However, my attempts to redirect stdout, stderr, or both, are not working.  For example, when I use:

```
time python process-column.py 2>/tmp/times.txt;
```

/tmp/times.txt does not get the output from time (it just prints out on the console).  I've also unsuccessfully tried:

```
 time python process-column.py >> /tmp/times.txt 2>&1;
```

The latter command does redirect the output of "python process-column.py" to the file.  However, I really want the output of "time" to go there (ideally, *only* the output of "time").  I would be so grateful for any help!  Thank you!

Comment: Maybe `/bin/time -o times.txt python...`?

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356628/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-the-time-command-to-a-file-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @doneal24 for the comment pointing to a very relevant answer in Stack Overflow.  The answer `[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13356654/3701355) solved this.

```
{ time sleep 1 ; } 2> time.txt
```

or

```
{ time sleep 1 2 > sleep.stderr; } 2> time.txt
```

will work.  The second snippet allows separation of sleep and time stderr streams.